# Glossary/Dictionary to display controlled loops

Tags: python

I have seen similar but nothing that answers my question on here.

I have a glossary set first. (for example 'word1' : 'definition1')

Now it's the loop i cannot seem to make. (first time) I am learning this and though after a couple of days cant seem to self teach.

Expected outcome:

**user_input**

"To see a word press w, to see a definition press d or to quit press q."

**user_input w**

word2

"press 'return' to see definition?"

definition2

"Press w for another word or press q to quit."

I have tried using a choice(word_gen) function and to pick a random word from the list when user presses 'w'.

```
word_diction = {'word1' : 'def1', 'word2' : 'def2', 'word3' : 'def3'}

word_gen= list(word_diction)

exit = False

while exit == False:
    opening_for_user = input('To see a word press w, to see a definition press d or to quit press q. ')
    if opening_for_user == 'w':
        print(('word:')XXX)

    if opening_for_user == 'q':
        exit = True
```

I placed XXX where i am struggling, i can imagine it's sloppy code but i am not aware of everything you can do on python yet. I was reading that you can use the return key as a button in these loops and would like to use it to display definition of the word after the word appears.

all feedback is welcomed!

I appreciate anyone that can give me the time.

Comment: my code didnt show in the box as expected.

Comment: If you highlight the code, and press ctrl-K it will format for you.

Comment: You marked a particular problem point with `XXXX`; I took that as your "proper" question in finding an answer.  Although describing the overall problem you need to solve is good context, you should not include various unsolved portions of the application.  If your current problem is making a random choice from a dict, then focus on that; mentioning "RETURN" as a button is a separate issue, separate research for you, and perhaps a separate SO posting.  If you separate the program into its component parts, you can look up most of the answers, even finding tutorials for most of them.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't complete code but hopefully a starting point for you. This will print just the first word, or the first definition. Let me know if need any help.

```
word_diction = {'word1' : 'def1', 'word2' : 'def2', 'word3' : 'def3'}

word_gen = list(word_diction.items())

exit = False

while exit == False:
    opening_for_user = input('To see a word press w, to see a definition press d or to quit press q. ')
    if opening_for_user == 'w':
        print('word:' + word_gen[0][0])

    if opening_for_user == 'd':
        print('definition:' + word_gen[0][1])

    if opening_for_user == 'q':
        exit = True
```

`word_gen` contains a list of tuples containing a bunch of `(word, definition)`

> eg: `[(word1, def1), (word2, def2)]`

so `word_gen[0]` gets you `(word1, def1)` and `word_gen[0][0]` gets you `word1`,

> can you see what `word_gen[0][1]` gets you then? or `word_gen[1][1]`?

**=====================================================================**
Something useful is the `break` keyword to help clean up code, it will break you out of loops when used, eg:

```
word_diction = {'word1' : 'def1', 'word2' : 'def2', 'word3' : 'def3'}

word_gen= list(word_diction)

while True:
    opening_for_user = input('To see a word press w, to see a definition press d or to quit press q. ')
    if opening_for_user == 'w':
        print('word:' + word_gen[0][0])

    if opening_for_user == 'd':
        print('definition:' + word_gen[0][1])

    if opening_for_user == 'q':
        break
```

Comment: Thank you, word_gen[0][1] is the def1, word_gen[1][1] was def2. Using this method would have create a seperate for the combinations from [0][0] - [3][3] am i right?

Comment: Sorry about late reply, but yes in a sense. But you can replace the number with a variable containing the numbers instead. so x  = 1, then [x][x] is [1][1]. That way you don't have to repeat code and can randomize the variable.